# Google Big Query: In a table with multiple company_id records, how to only output a row for each company id that appears in the table earliest?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working with the table that has the following information:

```
+----------+ | +----------+ | +-------+ | +-------+ |
    date     |  company_id  |  user_id  |  country  |
             |              |           |           |
 2020-07-01  |      1       |     3     |    USA    |    
 2020-04-01  |      1       |     2     |    USA    |
 2020-01-01  |      1       |     1     |    USA    |
```

For all countries in my table, my goal is to show number of company_id signups by country on rolling quarterly basis. I have already wrote a query to do all cleaning to output this data. Before my query is complete, there is one task remaining that I am struggling to solve.

Company with company_id 1 appears in the table 3 times, because at least 1 additional user signed up in 3 different quarters. What I am trying to do is to control output to only output same company_id once. Particularly, the row that appeared in the table the first. So, the desired output is:

```
   +----------+ | +----------+ | +-------+ | +-------+ |
       date     |  company_id  |  user_id  |  country  |
                |              |           |           |
    2020-01-01  |      1       |     1     |    USA    |
```

This way, even if my table contains multiple records of same company_id for every unique user, my SQL output will only show 1 unique company_id that appeared in the table the earliest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is:

```
select array_agg(t order by date asc limit 1)[ordinal(1)].*
from `table` t
group by t.company_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon! Trying to implement this now. After array_agg the first argument is 't'. What exact data is meant by that 't' in array_agg(t ...)? The table name?

Comment: @Arsik36 . . . `t` is the alias for the table in the `from` clause.

Comment: Gordon, thank you for this answer, it works! Can you explain one thing - what does [ordinal(1)].* do?

Comment: @Arsik36 . . . `array_agg()` returns an array.  The `[ordinal(1)].*` returns the first element and then expands it out.  You can also use `select as value`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY date LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY company_id
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, Mikhail!

Comment: sure. consider voting up the answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE date = (SELECT distinct min(date) first_date 
              FROM `project.dataset.table` 
              GROUP BY company_id);
```